# Error with installation IOS app to device builded in VS with Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I try to build app, created in VS with Xamarin, to test it on real device (on iPhoneSimulator it works without problem). I use AdHoc build with all needed certificates and provisions (created like [Xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ad-hoc-distribution/) describes). But when I try to upload IPA file to device through ITunes, it finish unsuccessfully. On iPhone it just disappear after uploading complete, on iPad it throw error message with "Application is unable to be install". Both devices was added to provision profile. Provision profile is active.
All help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can find a more descriptive reason if you open the "Deploying to Device" Window

[image: Menu -> View -> Pads -> Deploying to Device]

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see pictures from that image hosting.

Comment: Sorry, but still don't understand, where is this Menu, I need to open?

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus if you can't find it, locate the most right menu at the top (Help) and enter there "Deploying to Device" it would show you where it's located.

Comment: Got it. You mean VS for Mac. But I use VS for Windows. =)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved this way - copied project to Visual Studio for Mac, installed on host-build machine, building app, move project back. Now app is uploading without problems.